# Wordpress Gallery

Tags: wordpress, download, plugins, gallery, themes

[This](http://365psd.com/) website is based on wordpress, I wonder which plugin/theme are they using to customize wordpress into a gallery/download site.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with WordPress' thumbnail feature. You can assign a thumbnail to each post. It looks like that, and some tweaking to the theme in the way the posts are displayed and the download button is included.

Maybe there's a plugin to assign a file to download on each post, that's the only part I find complex in this theme.

Check these links:

- http://www.wpzoom.com/design/10-wordpress-themes-designed-for-photo-galleries/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=download

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure there're plugins and themes out there I can use without having to customize it all manually.

Comment: Check those links maybe they can help you find something similar.